# XML Not well formed in Firefox getting xml response from server

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jQGrid Latest version in my project.following is complete configuration that i configured.

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid( {
        url : 'Link.do?method=findAllBrand',
        mtype : 'GET',
        height : 350,
        datatype : "xml",
        colNames : [ 'Name' ],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'name',
            index : 'name',
            width : 620
        } ],
        rowNum : 10,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        sortname : 'id',
        sortorder : "desc",
        viewrecords : true,
        multiselect : true,
        imgpath : 'themes/base/images',
        caption : "Brand (s) Summary Grid",
        pager : $('#pager'),
        cache : false,
        onSelectRow : function(id) {

        }
    });
```

I am getting following data in form of xml from server :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><rows><page>1</page><total>1</total><records>4</records><row id="BRD00003"><cell>Blanco</cell></row><row id="BRD00001"><cell>Bosch</cell></row><row id="BRD00004"><cell>Chef</cell></row><row id="BRD00002"><cell>F&P</cell></row></rows>
```

i know that in the last cell of last row is creating problem , because it contains & char which has special meaning in the xml. however i have escaped sequence the whole xml using Apache commons lang library using below function.

```
toXml = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(toXml);
```

and the resulting string is

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt;&lt;rows&gt;&lt;page&gt;1&lt;/page&gt;&lt;total&gt;1&lt;/total&gt;&lt;records&gt;4&lt;/records&gt;&lt;row id=&quot;BRD00003&quot;&gt;&lt;cell&gt;Blanco&lt;/cell&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;row id=&quot;BRD00001&quot;&gt;&lt;cell&gt;Bosch&lt;/cell&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;row id=&quot;BRD00004&quot;&gt;&lt;cell&gt;Chef&lt;/cell&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;row id=&quot;BRD00002&quot;&gt;&lt;cell&gt;F&amp;P&lt;/cell&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;/rows&gt;
```

still i got the same error in Mozilla firefox latest version and in chrome , ie 7,8 also.

**I have to show you this special characters in the gird so how can i solve this problem ?**

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: Who controls the server? You'll have trouble repairing invalid xml. Must be fixed on server side.

Comment: @alxx please read my description carefully. i am asking to fix it at server side. i am generating the xml from server side.thanks

Comment: by the way jqGrid has no `cache` and `imgpath` parameters. The value of `pager` parameter you should better use in the string form. It should specify id selector: `pager: '#pager'`. You should additionally always use `gridview: true` option to improve performance of the grid and remove options having default values (like `mtype : 'GET'`, `datatype : "xml"`). The option `sortname : 'id'` is wrong. You mean probably `sortname : 'name'` or you should remove the option too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am generating the xml from server side.

Then escape each text node and each attribute value separately, it's all simple as that.

Comment: can you tell me how with example , i have already used StringEscapeUtils.

Comment: You are joining strings to get xml document, right? Escape content data before joining.

Comment: ...But obviously a more robust way is use some XML library to do that. It might be slower, though.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use JSON format instead of XML whenever it's possible.

If you do need to use XML and you need to place some general values in XML you need use CDATA construct (`<![CDATA["some common text"]]>`).

Additionally I would recommend you to use `autoencode: true` as your standard jqGrid options. In the case you will be able to place any text in jqGrid cells. jqGrid will do the encoding of all characters which have special meaning for HTML.

Comment: thanks mr. Oleg i will use all this options for optimizing my grids.