# Paging does not work in JqGrid

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jQGrid Latest version in my project.following is complete configuration that i configured.

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid( {
        url : 'Link.do?method=findAllBrand',
        mtype : 'GET',
        height : 350,
        datatype : "xml",
        colNames : [ 'Name' ],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'name',
            index : 'name',
            width : 620
        } ],
        rowNum : 10,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        sortname : 'id',
        sortorder : "desc",
        viewrecords : true,
        multiselect : true,
        imgpath : 'themes/base/images',
        caption : "Brand (s) Summary Grid",
        pager : #pager,
        cache : false,
        onSelectRow : function(id) {

        }
    });
```

I am getting following data in form of xml from server :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><rows><page>1</page><total>4</total><records>75</records><row id="BRD00005"><cell>AEG</cell></row><row id="BRD00010"><cell>ARC</cell></row><row id="BRD00006"><cell>Aga</cell></row><row id="BRD00007"><cell>Allenzi </cell></row><row id="BRD00008"><cell>Amana</cell></row><row id="BRD00009"><cell>Andi</cell></row><row id="BRD00011"><cell>Arda</cell></row><row id="BRD00012"><cell>Ariston</cell></row><row id="BRD00013"><cell>Asko</cell></row><row id="BRD00014"><cell>Baumatic</cell></row><row id="BRD00015"><cell>Bendix</cell></row><row id="BRD00003"><cell>Blanco</cell></row><row id="BRD00001"><cell>Bosch</cell></row><row id="BRD00004"><cell>Chef</cell></row><row id="BRD00016"><cell>Damani</cell></row><row id="BRD00017"><cell>Davell</cell></row><row id="BRD00018"><cell>Delonghi</cell></row><row id="BRD00019"><cell>Dishlex</cell></row><row id="BRD00020"><cell>Electrolux</cell></row><row id="BRD00021"><cell>Emilia</cell></row><row id="BRD00022"><cell>Euro</cell></row><row id="BRD00023"><cell>Eurolec</cell></row><row id="BRD00024"><cell>Euromaid</cell></row><row id="BRD00002"><cell>F&amp;P</cell></row><row id="BRD00027"><cell>FP</cell></row><row id="BRD00025"><cell>Fagor</cell></row><row id="BRD00026"><cell>Fisher And Paykel</cell></row><row id="BRD00028"><cell>Franke</cell></row><row id="BRD00030"><cell>GE</cell></row><row id="BRD00034"><cell>GVA</cell></row><row id="BRD00029"><cell>Gaggenau</cell></row><row id="BRD00031"><cell>Glem </cell></row><row id="BRD00032"><cell>Glem Gas</cell></row><row id="BRD00033"><cell>Glemgas</cell></row><row id="BRD00035"><cell>Haier</cell></row><row id="BRD00036"><cell>Hisense </cell></row><row id="BRD00037"><cell>Hitachi</cell></row><row id="BRD00038"><cell>Hoover</cell></row><row id="BRD00039"><cell>Hotpoint</cell></row><row id="BRD00040"><cell>IAG</cell></row><row id="BRD00041"><cell>Ilve</cell></row><row id="BRD00042"><cell>Indesit</cell></row><row id="BRD00043"><cell>Jenn Air</cell></row><row id="BRD00044"><cell>Kelvinator </cell></row><row id="BRD00045"><cell>Kleenmaid</cell></row><row id="BRD00047"><cell>LG</cell></row><row id="BRD00046"><cell>La Germania</cell></row><row id="BRD00048"><cell>Liebherr</cell></row><row id="BRD00049"><cell>Linea</cell></row><row id="BRD00050"><cell>Lofra</cell></row><row id="BRD00051"><cell>Maytag</cell></row><row id="BRD00052"><cell>Midea</cell></row><row id="BRD00053"><cell>Miele</cell></row><row id="BRD00054"><cell>NEC</cell></row><row id="BRD00055"><cell>Neff</cell></row><row id="BRD00056"><cell>Nobel</cell></row><row id="BRD00057"><cell>Omega</cell></row><row id="BRD00058"><cell>Onix</cell></row><row id="BRD00059"><cell>Panasonic </cell></row><row id="BRD00060"><cell>Robinhood</cell></row><row id="BRD00061"><cell>Sagi</cell></row><row id="BRD00062"><cell>Samsung</cell></row><row id="BRD00063"><cell>Seimen </cell></row><row id="BRD00064"><cell>Sharp</cell></row><row id="BRD00065"><cell>Simpson</cell></row><row id="BRD00066"><cell>Smeg</cell></row><row id="BRD00067"><cell>St George</cell></row><row id="BRD00068"><cell>Technika</cell></row><row id="BRD00069"><cell>Techno</cell></row><row id="BRD00070"><cell>Technogas</cell></row><row id="BRD00071"><cell>Teka</cell></row><row id="BRD00072"><cell>Thor</cell></row><row id="BRD00073"><cell>Vintec</cell></row><row id="BRD00074"><cell>Westinghouse</cell></row><row id="BRD00075"><cell>Whirlpool</cell></row></rows>
```

I have modified the pager parameter as suggested by user Oleg in the other post.but still the pager is not working as expected. initially it shows only the 10 data of the record , when i click on next it does nothing.

```
what did i do wrong
```

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `pager` option must be quoted: `pager : "#pager"`. You use `datatype: "xml"` *without* `loadonce: true`. In the case **your server (`url : 'Link.do?method=findAllBrand'`) is responsible for paging and sorting**. If the user click on the next page new request to the server with the corresponding parameters `page=2`.

Typically the server should return the number of items which corresponds `page` and `rows` parameters. The XML response contains much more items. I suppose that the server returns *all items* independent from the requested page. In the case you should include `loadonce: true`. In the case the client code (JavaScript code of jqGrid) will do paging and sorting for you. If you use `loadonce: true` option you can remove the part

```xml
<page>1</page><total>4</total><records>75</records>
```

from the XML data returned from the server.

Additionally I would recommend you to consider to change to use JSON instead of XML whenever it's possible. In the case you could reduce the representation of items like

```xml
<rows>
<row id="BRD00022"><cell>Euro</cell></row>
<row id="BRD00002"><cell>F&amp;P</cell></row>
<row id="BRD00026"><cell>Fisher And Paykel</cell></row>
</rows>
```

to

```json
[["Euro","BRD00022"],["F&P","BRD00002"],["Fisher And Paykel","BRD00026"]]
```

So you can reduce the size of transferred data.

Additionally, like I wrote you in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492887/xml-not-well-formed-in-firefox-getting-xml-response-from-server#comment18464513_13492887) to your previous question, you should replace `sortname : 'id'` to `sortname : 'name'` bacsue your grid don't have the column with the name `"id"`. The option  `sortorder : "desc"` should be probably removed.

You should remove [deprecated option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options) `imgpath` and remove option `cache` which not exist in jqGrid too. Instead of that I strictly recommend you to add `gridview: true` option and `autoencode: true`. If you use `autoencode: true` you will don't need to use HTML encoding (converting `F&P` to `F&amp;P` on the server side).

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Mihir.htm) demonstrate how the grid could looks like:

[image]

I included toolbar filter and advanced searching in the grid to show how easy one can implement the features if one uses `loadonce: true`.

Comment: Mr. Oleg if i removed imgPath then what should i use instead of it ??

Comment: it is the perfect answer , it looks like Mr. Oleg has absolute knowledge of jQGrid. I have seen so many answers from this user on jqGrid forum also.again thanks Mr. Oleg and please do not remove the jQGrid page for some time i want to study it.thanks

Comment: @Mihir: You are welcome! jqGrid don't know `imgpath` at all and just ignore it exactly like any other fantase option `foo: "bar"`. In very vary old version of jqGrid one don't used jQuery UI CSS and the option was needed. About [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Mihir.htm) or any other old demos which I created for old answers: I don't removed any from there from the web server. I think that URL will be not broken for many time.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg by the way it looks like you r consultant by profession and you r from Germany.actually i am the server side developer , i have to to this client side work because Our UI developer has suddenly left the job , and i know some of the jQuery so i accept this task anyway i am lucky i found you.in the future i invite you for all the jQuery related question.